# Fresh Laravel 5.4 Project, webpack not working

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js

So Laravel made their new fancy wrapper for webpack called Laravel mix.

According to the docs, you compile the frontend files by running `npm run watch`.
The problem is that webpack doesn't detect any file changes. The only fix I've found is to add `--watch-poll` to the `watch` task config. The problem with that, is that:

> it uses native file listeners to check for updates.

And the problem with that is that it uses like a 105% of your CPU. Do I really have to settle for this? Is there a smarter solution for this, or even a gulp equivalent task setup for Laravel's front-end files?

Haven't found an elegant way to do this with any gulp packages ( gulp-vueify just compiles components into js files ).

Is there any solution for Windows hosts?

Thanks

EDIT:

Using Windows 10 and Laravel's Homestead ( NodeJS v6.9.0 )

Comment: From what I've heard, Windows is a pain in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird that nobody found a solution.

I found something a bit janky, but it definitely does the job.
Find the file `DirectoryWatcher.js` located in `/node_modules/webpack/lib/`.

On *line 57*, replace the `ignored` option with `ignored: /node_modules/,`.
This means that any `ignored` option you initially pass through will get overwritten, but if I knew how to pass them in the right way, I wouldn't be doing it like this.

It still works fine. CPU usage is down and compilation time is reduced greatly.